# show multiple products foreach row in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

i am making a latest product list in php by getting data from database. I want to echo 18 latest products from my database. I am having outer html for each item which will be echoed for all the pruducts with different data. Below is query for getting latest products

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM devices ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3") or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
```

and here is the html:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 nopadding">  

            <div class="device_box">                        


                <a title="'.$row['name'].'" href="'.$row['link'].'"><img class="img-responsive" alt="'.$row['name'].'" title="'.$row['name'].'" src="'.$row['img'].'" /></a>


                <span>

                <a title="'.$row['name'].'" href="'.$row['link'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a>

                <br /><div class="price_small">'.$row['price'].'</div>
                </span>

            </div>              

        </div>
```

And i want to echo 18 products using foreach loop. I tried using foreach but it shows error.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Any help will be appriciated. thanks.

Comment: where is foreach loop code?

Comment: I dont know how can i make loop for each product.
`$data[]=$row;
foreach($query as $data)
  if (!empty($data)){
  $id = $data["id"];
  $name = $data["name"];
`

Comment: you apply limit 3 and you want to show 18 products. ???????

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't assign the $row to $data like this $data[] = $row. Also while loop can sort your problem, don't go for foreach. Use this:

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM devices ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3") or die(mysql_error());

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){ ?>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 nopadding">  

            <div class="device_box">                        


                <a title="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>" href="<?php echo $row['link'] ?>"><img class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>" title="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>" src="<?php echo $row['img'] ?>" /></a>


                <span>

                <a title="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>" href="<?php echo $row['link'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></a>

                <br /><div class="price_small"><?php echo $row['price'] ?></div>
                </span>

            </div>              

        </div>


   <?php  } ?>
```

Comment: Good. Welcome bro. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sql = "sql query";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 nopadding">
        <div class="device_box">
            <a title="'.$row['name'].'" href="'.$row['link'].'"><img class="img-responsive" alt="'.$row['name'].'" title="'.$row['name'].'" src="'.$row['img'].'" /></a>
            <span>
            <a title="'.$row['name'].'" href="'.$row['link'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a>
            <br /><div class="price_small">'.$row['price'].'</div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
```

Comment: Its showing error for all values: Notice: Undefined index: name in

Comment: make sure with your sql query
select name, link, img, price....
you have to right query properly my code is right

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
    <? 
$sql = "YOUR QUERY HERE";
$result = mysql_query($conn, $sql);
//if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
foreach($data as $key=>$val) { ?>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 nopadding">
        <div class="device_box">
            <a title="<?php echo $val['name']; ?>" href="<?php echo $val['link'];?>"><img class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $val['name'];?>" title="<?php echo $val['name'];?>" src="<?php echo $val['img'];?>" /></a>
            <span>
            <a title="<?php echo $val['name'];?>" href="<?php echo $val['link'];?>"><?php echo $val['name'];?></a>
            <br /><div class="price_small"><?php echo $val['price'];?></div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>';
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Whats the need of multiple loops? and also where did you used the $key? so i think foreach is useless.

Comment: This is because of re-usability of $data - associative array. If you want to do so every time you must have to use while loop which is very irritating, instead of doing this you just make one associate array for your data results and then  try whatever you want.

Comment: You are right, but we use foreach if we need the keys actually but here is the case, you didn't use the $key inside the foreach. While loop might be irritating for you but it helps a lot. Also my solution works for the user.

Comment: You are not getting me what I am saying. Actually my intense is to do so is to reuse the result of the query for the other side. do again do the same process? do you again fetch the data? e.g. mysql_fetch_array()??? In this case if you have $data as a result array you can easily do the other process as your all records which was from your last query. Ahhhhaaa... still if you are not getting me leave it. and do as your own way. Every developer has their own way to do code.

Comment: Yes i got your point. you are good at your point but for now we are not sure about the user's approach of using the query data. No doubt your solution works good when the case of reusuability.